# InfoPath 2010: The file is not a valid XML file, but it is?

Tags: infopath

My InfoPath 2010/VSTA dev machine was recently rebuilt with Office 2016/InfoPath 2013.

In order to edit/maintain existing InfoPath 2010 forms with C# code behind, I had to back-rev my Office install to Office 2010.

I've had problems with interrelated forms ever since...

I have a '`PDM Contacts`' Form that is used as a Data Connection in several other forms.

The published versions of these forms all work fine, with the parent forms accessing the PDM Contacts Data Connection without issue. I can open the PDM Contacts form, add/remove/edit field entries, add/remove rows, etc., with no issues.

When editing these forms in InfoPath Designer, however, the PDM Contacts Data Connection fails, throwing the following error:

> InfoPath cannot open the following file:
>   .../sites/forms/PDMContacts/PDMContacts.xml.

The same error is thrown when opening the PDMContacts form file in InfoPath Designer.

I have scoured the web for some guidance but have not found a solution to this issue...

What can I do to resolve this problem?